# How to link to specific part of a page in wordpress permalinks

Tags: links, permalinks

I have a one page template(muse theme) which its main menu items link to a specific part of the page in the webpage itself. I want to add `#` character before post name to go to the specific part of the page just like **wikipedia**. How can I do that in permalinks?
It doesn't allow `#` character.

Comment: Do you mean this? Is a link from wikipedia. `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordpress#Awards` If yes, this only a anker inside the html, there is always possible to add to each link url. You find more information in html documentation about anker.

Comment: @bueltge, No I mean its not in my post, its a navigation menu which I've defined in menus section. Its a primary menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works, currently not tested. Only a idea to enhance for the custom var.
Also I don't the goal right.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ) {

  $vars[] = '#';
  return $vars;
}
```

A other hint is the [link to the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Plugin_Hooks), to filter the rewrite of WP.

Comment: It doesn't work buddy, I want http://localhost/#services . It  produces http://localhost/services

Comment: Do you have seen the example on the codex link? It have a example to create new rule.

Comment: Yes I saw it and tried it but it doesn't work